# In gimp file-open menu all dates are shown "unknown"

Tags: filesystems, gimp, date

As shown in [this link](https://i.postimg.cc/630bMKtW/gimp-issue.png):

> [image: Open image dialog]

I have windows 10, installed less than month ago. Gimp is 2.8.22  fresh install with some plugins, scripts and addons added from my previous install. New install works not either.

Comment: Are the files on C:? IIRC sometimes you have to tell Windows to let a given application access the disk.

Comment: Every file is like that on every drive

Comment: Could it be just gimp expecting a different time format? Like gimp expects mm/dd/yyyy but gets dd/mm/yyyy instead? Or something like that? How could I change gimp to correct time format?

Comment: No, Gimp get the file timestamps through a system call that returns a number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. This kind of display usually means that Gimp can read the directory (so has a list of files to check) but cannot access the files themselves (no read rights on them) for some reason.

Comment: @xenoid How do you check and change those settings? Gimp still opens, saves and shows the previews just fine for the images.

Comment: Um... 2.8.22? Did you try 2.10?

Comment: I don't want to switch to 2.10 because it has that rotating view thing that can not be turned off.

Comment: The weird thing is that even if the dates show unknown like in the image I added clicking the modified button still sorts the files by last modified date in the window. So if you click it the newest edited files come on top or bottom based on their dates. This does not being me any closer to solution though.I can try installing 2.10 to see if the problem persist in that but I don't want to switch to 2.10

Answer (score 0):

(can't add a comment, not enough street cred)

Confirming baviros's observations above for Win 10 Home 64bit and GIMP **2.10.12**, installed today:

"Modified" column in File-Open dialog shows "Unknown" for all entries (both folders and files), but still can *sort* correctly both ways.
*Not* a folder access permission issue as this is not the drive where Win10 lives (and "run as admin" doesn't help either).